# How do you adjust for edge to edge screen without compromising minimum api level in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, screen

I am developing an app, however, I have noticed on phones that have edge-to-edge screens, the black notch at the top blocks out some of the features I've added in (for instance, information on the action bar).

I know there are simple fixes such as using

```
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
  </item>
```

within the activity style, however, I have noticed that the incision of this requires a minimum API level of 27, which is much higher than the minimum of 14 I have been trying to maintain, and I don't want to cut out that high of a percentage of the market.

Do any of you know how to deal with edge-to-edge screen layouts without compromising the minimum API level?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to just use newer API, as since then new models with notch started showing up on market (thus Android introduced that API), keeping API 14 as min. You can still support older devices without calling non-existing methods from newer APIs. As you have here only one attribute in XML - these aren't resolved on older OS versions, but don't break nothing

PS. Note that before Android introduced this API there was some freshly introduced devices with notch and you don't have any option for proper handling layout on them (too old for API, device manufacturer didn't provide any API either). But most (all?) of them got update to API27, so your issue may occur only on never-updated devices with "experimental" notch